# Count adyacent non-blank cells in Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have an Excel/Google Sheets table in which some rows contain blank cells in between non-blank cells. I would like to count from left to right. I have used the formula COUNTA(A2:F2) but it cannot achieve what I want. This is a sample of the outcome I would like to get, with the Personalized count that I am seeking to achieve and the classic COUNTA:
[image]

Comment: I can't understand why in the first row Count=5 while there are 6 no blank cells and 0 blank cells.

Comment: True, my mistake. See the table updated.

Comment: So first two results (6 and 4) are counting filled cells, but last two results are counting empty cells. How do we know which you want to do?

Comment: I want to count from left to right non-empty cells. When the count encounters a blank cell, it stops there. So in row 4 it will stop counting after "157" and in row 3 it will stop counting after "70"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the task is slightly different from what you describe in the question, you want to count *until* blank and not *between* not blank cells.

So I made this working example

```
+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|   |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |  E   |  F   |   G   |
+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 1 | 2021 | 2020 | 2019 | 2018 | 2017 | 2016 | Count |
| 2 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 | 6     |
| 3 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |      |      | 4     |
| 4 |    1 |      |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 | 1     |
| 5 |    1 |    1 |    1 |      |      |    1 | 3     |
+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

where cell `G2` contains the following:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(1;--(A2:F2="");0)-1;COUNTA(A2:F2))
```

is it right for you?

Comment: Yes, I want to count until blank but the issue is that there are blank cells in between non-blank cells. But thank you for the clarification. Regarding your solution, it works on Excel but not on Google Sheets. What could be the issue?

Comment: I could solve it by using an array formula in Google Sheets with CRTL+SHITF+ENTER

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your question

Comment: @Nicolas741 make a decision on what program to use. Google is not the same as Excel especially when using array formula's.